# ARP request without reply raw sockets python

Tags: python, sockets, arp

I'm trying to get a arp reply after send ARP request but the reply is not comming.

I had a look to wireshark for the results and i think he does the broadcast to the network, but no reply show up...

In results of wireshark the MAC addr of sender and receiver is do not correspond to the real MAC addr, im bealive i'm not packing this right but i dont understand why.

need help...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import struct
import socket



raw = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(0x0806))
raw.bind(("wlp3s0", socket.htons(0x0806)))


mac_local = b"ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"   # mac de quem envia request
ip_local = "192.168.1.7"           # ip de quem envia request
mac_dest = b"00:00:00:00:00:00"    # mac de quem recebe request
ip_dest = "192.168.1.2"            # ip de quem recebe request




# Ethernet Header
protocol = 0x0806             # 0x0806 protocol to ARP
ethernet_header = struct.pack("!6s6sH", mac_dest, mac_local, protocol)


# ARP header

type_hardware = 1
type_protocol = 0x0800       # IPV4
size_addr_hardware = 6   # Refere ao tamanho do endereço do MAC que é 
48 bits  == 6 bytes 
size_addr_protocol = 4  # Refere ao tamanho do endereço do ipv4 que é 
32 bits == 4 bytes
operation = 1                  # 1 = request / 2 = Reply 

source_ip = socket.inet_aton(ip_local)
dest_ip = socket.inet_aton(ip_dest)


arp_addr = struct.pack("!HHBBH6s4s6s4s", type_hardware, type_protocol,
                       size_addr_hardware, size_addr_protocol, operation,
                       mac_local, source_ip, mac_dest, dest_ip)
pkt = ethernet_header + arp_addr

cont = 0
while cont < 6:
    raw.send(pkt)
    cont +=1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfzvI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etdqV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mac_dest` and `mac_local` are definitely not right. You've just created a byte string with the ASCII value. Each of those is 17 bytes long. And you're just taking the first 6 of those 17 bytes for each of the addresses.

They should be something like this instead:

```
mac_dest = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
mac_local = b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

Check that the length of the byte string before the `struct.pack` call is exactly six bytes.

Also, not sure what you're trying to do, but I doubt it makes sense to use the all-zero hardware address as a *destination* address. Pretty sure no one will receive that as it would be a unicast to an address that no one has. The opposite might be helpful (send to the broadcast address *from* all-zero) -- I think that's standard for ARP probes.

Comment: Im trying to understand how send broadcast with raw sockets and python.

Comment: @Gabrielcosta With a raw socket, you just send an Ethernet packet with the broadcast address (all 1s == ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) as the destination. Typically, by default, a network adapter will *only* receive packets sent directly to its MAC address, or packets sent to the MAC broadcast address. Packets sent to other addresses are ignored. (Note that the destination address comes *first* in the Ethernet header.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm somehow confused about the accepted answer.

Is MAC 00:00:00: 00:00:00 not a valid MAC from XEROX?

https://hwaddress.com/company/xerox-corporation/

When I see ARP-request captured with e.g wireshark

then mac adresses in requests are always like

```
MAC_DST: FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  //mac broadcast
MAC_SRC: MAC-address of requester
```

the mac adresses in reply would then be

```
MAC_DST: MAC-adress of requester
MAC_SRC: MAC-address of replier
```